# Collect distributed sums

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation

I have another task that somehow should be trivial. Suppose I have the following expression

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{2}{9} x_i + 2 \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{9} x_i, $$

or in Mathematica-FullForm

```
Plus[Sum[Times[Rational[2,9],Subscript[x,i]],List[i,1,n]],Times[2,Sum[Times[Rational[1,9],Subscript[x,i]],List[i,1,n]]]]
```

Obviously, this is equal to $ \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{4}{9} x_i $ but Mathematica 6 wouldn't see that. How can I teach Mathematica to simplify this expression in a most general way (the actual expressions I need to simplify are way more complicated, they involve *multiple sums* and are mostly generated by some other routines)?

EDIT (21.04.2015): By *multiple sums*, I meant the following general expression:
$$ a \sum_{i_1=1}^n \ldots\sum_{i_k=1}^n b\cdot f(x_{i_1},\ldots,x_{i_k}) + c \sum_{i_1=1}^n \ldots \sum_{i_k=1}^n d\cdot g(x_{i_1},\ldots,x_{i_k}). $$
The constants $a,b,c,d$ may be arbitrarily complex, the $k$ may vary as well. I needed a rule that, when applied, produces
$$ \sum_{i_1=1}^n \ldots \sum_{i_k=1}^n \left((a\cdot b) f(x_{i_1},\ldots,x_{i_k}) + (c \cdot d) g(x_{i_1},\ldots,x_{i_k})\right). $$

Based on your replies, I have concocted an amazingly simple solution :

```
HoldPattern[a_ Sum[c_, y___]] :> Sum[a c, y]
HoldPattern[Sum[a_ b_, y___] + Sum[c_ b_, y___]] :> Sum[Together[a+c] b, y]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider this,

```
rl= (a_. Sum[b_. Subscript[x_, i_], {i_, i0_: 1, n_}]) :> 
   Sum[(a b) Subscript[x, i], {i, i0, n}];

exp = Sum[2/9 Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, n}] + 
   2 Sum[1/9 Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, n}];
```

Apply transformation rule repeatedly:

```
exp //. rl
```

[image]

Collecting more than two sums:

```
exp1 = 1 Sum[3/9 Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, n}] + 
  3 Sum[1/9 Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, n}] + 
  3 Sum[2/9 Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, n}]
```

[image]

```
exp1 //. rl
```

resulting in

[image]

Comment: Can you please comment, why do you use the `Default `pattern (`_.`) here? What is the idea behind?

Answer (score 1):

Use a replacement rule

```
rule = (a1_. * Sum[c1_. Subscript[x_, i_], {i_, i0_: 1, n_}] +
     a2_. * Sum[c2_. Subscript[x_, i_], {i_, i0_: 1, n_}]) :>
   Sum[(a1*c1 + a2*c2) Subscript[x, i], {i, i0, n}];

expr = Sum[2/9 Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, n}] +
   2 Sum[1/9 Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, n}];

expr /. rule
```

> Sum[(4*Subscript[x, i])/9, {i, 1, n}]

Comment: Can you please comment, why do you use the `Default `pattern (`_.`) here? What is the idea behind?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch - without the defaults `expr` won't match the pattern in `rule`. Define a `rule2` without the defaults and evaluate `expr /. rule2`

Comment: Yes, Bob, I understand that. I already played with it.  My question is more, why it does not match without and matches with that definition?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch - because the rule is more general than the specific example (`expr`). The rule allows additional factors which may or may not be present and in this case not all are present. To handle the missing factors the defaults must be explicitly invoked. For example only one of the sums in `expr` has an external factor but the rule handles none, one (either), or both.

Comment: Hanllon OK, thank you. This approach seems to should work also for integrals, such as  `expr = 3*Integrate[g[x], {x, 0, 1}] `and `rule = a_.*Integrate[f_[x], {x, a_: 0, b_}] -> 
  a*Integrate[f[x], {x, a, b}] ` but it does not. The operation `expr /. rule `returns the initial expression. Could you please comment on the reason and difference?

Comment: OK, thank you. Please disregard the above comment: there is an error in the code. There is one still elusive feature. The method seems to be also applicable to integrals. Indeed, assume the expression `expr = 3*Integrate[g[x], {x, 0, 1}] ` and the rule: `rule = a_.*Integrate[b_.*f_[x], {x, a_: 0, b_}] -> Integrate[a*b*f[x], {x, a, b}] `. Its application `expr /. rule` returns the same expression. So, what is the difference? Could you comment?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch - your latest comments are off-topic for this question, i.e., do not relate to "Collect distributed sums." Please open a new question.

Comment: No, it is not. It is just a generalization

Answer (score 0):

I found this question after having solved a similar issue. Here is my solution:

```
r = (a0_:1) Sum[t0_, i__] + (a1_:1) Sum[t1_, i__] :> Sum[a0 t0 + a1 t1, i]
```

Then, given the example in the accepted answer, recursively apply the rule:

```
exp1 = 1 Sum[3/9 Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, n}] + 
  3 Sum[1/9 Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, n}] + 
  3 Sum[2/9 Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, n}]

InputForm[% //. r]
```

> ```
> Sum[(4*Subscript[x, i])/3, {i, 1, n}]
> ```